# https request in chrome packaged app (java script)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

I'm trying to send a request from chrome packaged app:

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxxapps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20email", //"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me",

jsonp: "responseText",

dataType: "jsonp",

data: {
    q: "select *",
    format: "json"
},

success: function( response ) {
    console.log( response ); 
}
});
```

and recieving the following error:

```
Refused to load the script
 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxx&q=select+*&format=json&_=xxx'
  because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
 "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that
 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

The manifest file of the app contains following:

```
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://accounts.google.com; object-src 'self'"
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Make sure you reload the extension on chrome://extensions after you change the manifest.

Comment: @abraham, did it again. Same result: There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
'content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.

Comment: Have you tried adding `https://accounts.google.com/*` to your permissins array?

Comment: You'll also want to stop using jsonp and just do a straight XHR request with a JSON payload.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages you're seeing are the answer. The first one was saying you were violating CSP. The second is saying you can't change CSP in a Chrome App.

Read more about [Content Security Policy in a Chrome App](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval.html), and for completeness [another discussion in the context of Chrome Extensions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html). You have the answer to the question you asked, but you might want to ask a new question explaining what you're trying to do (as opposed to why you're seeing these error messages). If your overall goal is to run external (i.e., downloaded) content in a Chrome App, the only way to do it according to the Chrome Web Store's developer terms of service is to sandbox the code and message to/from your normal, privileged code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it by adding to manifest:
  "permissions": ["https://accounts.google.com/"]